# pythonを用いた画像分類の機械学習で画像データをXとyデータに分けたときのyデータの処理がうまくいかない

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow

最近、機械学習を学び始めたものです。

タイトルのようにpythonを用いた画像分類モデルを作成しようと思っています。
現在、ライブラリ、画像の読み込みまでは正常に動作していることを確認しています。

問題としては、データをX_train、y_trainに分けたときにy_trainの結果が[4]と返されてしまう点です。
各データの分類値である[0,1,2,3,4]のいずれかの数字が画像データの数だけ返すようにしたいです。

以下、コードになります。
拙い文章、コードで分かりづらいと思いますが、ご教授していただければと思います。

```
#ライブラリのインポート
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import glob

#ファイルからtrainデータとtestデータをそれぞれ読み込む
    for f in glob.glob("/content/drive/MyDrive/deeplearning-day3-classifing-apples/*/*/*.jpg"):    
    img_data = tf.io.read_file(f)
    img_data = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img_data)
    img_data = tf.image.resize(img_data,[100,100])
    for r in glob.glob("/content/drive/MyDrive/deeplearning-day3-classifing-apples/*/*.jpg"):    
    img_data_test = tf.io.read_file(r)
    img_data_test = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img_data_test)
    img_data_test = tf.image.resize(img_data_test,[100,100])

#画像データをXとyに分ける
X_train = []
y_train = []
X_test = []
y_test = []

X_train.append(img_data)
y_train.append(int(f.split("/")[6].split("_")[0]))
X_test.append(img_data_test)
y_test.append(int(r.split("/")[6].split("-")[0]))

#numpyに変換
X_train = np.array(X_train) / 255.0
y_train = np.array(y_train)
X_test = np.array(X_test) / 255.0
y_test = np.array(y_test)

#それぞれの画像データの形式
train例... /content/drive/MyDrive/deeplearning-day3-classifing-apples/train/0_Bread/0.jpg
test例... /content/drive/MyDrive/deeplearning-day3-classifing-apples/test/0-0.jpg
```

[image: 階層の写真]

Comment: コードのインデントがおかしいようですのでご確認ください。また「y_trainの結果が[4]と返されてしまう」というのはどの時点のy_trainのことでしょうか？

Comment: インデントの件、失礼いたしました。
#numpyに変換後のy_trainになります。

Comment: まだインデントがおかしいのでなんとも言えませんが、1つの画像についての`X`と`y`が得られたら（次の画像に行って上書きする前に）すぐリストに追加しないとダメじゃないでしょうか。